# Group by with inner joins returning too many records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

A table has a foundStatus column that's a char. I want to return a list of foundStatuses with a count next to each - this works:

```
SELECT foundstatus, count(foundstatus) as total
FROM findings f
WHERE findDateTime BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND '2017-06-24 23:59:59'
group by foundstatus
order by foundstatus
```

I need to join several tables to build a where clause - and doing so begins to return too many columns. I can get this to work:

```
SELECT foundstatus, count(foundstatus) as total
FROM findings f left join
     pets p
     on f.petid = p.petid
WHERE findDateTime BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND '2017-06-24 23:59:59' 
group by foundstatus
order by foundstatus
```

By doing a left join, however - any subsequent joins I do (left or inner) just returns too many rows (I guess because multiple records from joined tables are being returned):

```
SELECT foundstatus, count(foundstatus) as total
FROM findings f left join
     pets p
     on f.petid = p.petid inner join
     petTags pt
     ON p.petID = pt.petID 
WHERE findDateTime BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND '2017-06-24 23:59:59' 
group by foundstatus
order by foundstatus
```

I need a statement like the bottom only with 5 joined tables to return the same counts as the top 2 queries. I'm sure this is fairly easy but can find nothing on Google - how can I do it? Thx.

Comment: How do people rack up so many points on Stack Overflow and not know how to format code?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I actually liked his way more than yours --I like the join on a new line and the table name associated with that join on the same line.  So a line has FROM <file it is from>  or JOIN <table to join>

Comment: One of the best question i read in here , always a pleasure to read your answers prof. @Gordon

Comment: @niico -- The way I always fix this problem is to figure out why the joins are causing multiple records -- When it happens to me it means I don't understand the logic of the join well enough to specify a single record for the join.  Once I look carfully I can filter those extras in the join.  It is interesting to me that you don't show us the code that is causing the problem.  Often you will get a better answer if you do so.

Comment: @Hogan I was thinking along those lines - but I can't work out how to restrict the join to - effectively - eliminate the multiple rows.

Comment: @niico -- this is my point -- if you showed us the joins you can't restrict we could tell you how -- in this way when you show the code you are having problems with we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a primary key in `findings` you can do:

```
select f.foundstatus, count(distinct f.findingsId) as total
from findings f left join
     pets p
     on f.petid = p.petid left join
     petTags pt
     on p.petID = pt.petID 
where f.findDateTime >= '2008-01-01' and
      f.findDateTime < '2017-06-25' 
group by f.foundstatus
order by foundstatus;
```

Often, `count(distinct)` is not the best way to go.  My guess is that `EXISTS` conditions in the `WHERE` clause are  better way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks - this actually returns counts that are *too low* this time. For example a valid foundStatus = 'I'. This is present 5 times in the findings table - but the above SQL only returns 3. (3 of the 5 have the same related petID - which I assume is the reason, only 1 of those 3 is being counted, +2 more for a total of 3).

Comment: how about `count(distinct petId)`?

Comment: OK I solved it - it just required 2 left joins. Thanks!

Comment: How would you use an exists condition in the where clause in this example? That sounds better - never done it before.

Comment: Use EXISTS() to determine if what you are trying to figure out happens ever, it short circuits after finding a single positive result. In this case I believe it would apply to testing your foundstatus against findings; if you have no findings you have no found status.

Comment: @niico -- Gordan did not mean to use EXISTS() as Anthony suggests he meant to use `AND` in the join line -- for example lets say that you have a pet food table that lists all the pet foods the pet likes and gives them a ordering with 1 being the most liked.  If you says `LEFT JOIN FOOD F ON  P.PETID = F.PETID` this will give you multiple rows but `LEFT JOIN FOOD F ON  P.PETID = F.PETID AND F.RANK = 1` will only give you one row.